# Having a date inside a div with innerHTML content

Tags: html, angular

I have a `<div>` and I want to have the date inside it. (For some reasons I can't change this configuration) This box may have a text with html properties. It is clear that I should use `[innerHTML]` but when using it, I can't put the date inside the `<div>`. I'm wondering if there is any way to have the text  **without showing the properties like `<br/>` and having a line break instead, and also having the date just inside the div?**

Here is my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8qqruf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```js
text = 'Hi<br/>How are you?';
```

```html
<div>{{ text }}</div>
<hr/>
<div>{{ text }}<span>HH:MM</span></div>
<hr/>
<div [innerHTML]="text"></div>
<hr/>
<div [innerHTML]="text"><span>HH:MM</span></div>
```

The snippet is not working because it is not Angular. Please refer to my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your `<br>` tags with `\n` and then add CSS to preserve the line break:

```
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```
<div>{{ text }}</div>
```

```
text = 'Hi\nHow are you?';
```

Answer (score 1):

To put html content to the `div`, it is needed to convert the html code to stay safe from XSS using `DomSanitizer`.

So it will be good to generate a new pipe to do this action as follows.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 public transform(value: any, type: string): any {
     const sanitizedContent = DOMPurify.sanitize(value);
     return angular.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(sanitizedContent);

  }
}
```

And on the main module, you can import this pipe and can use it as follows.

```
<div [innerHTML]="text | safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a question. Does your solution makes it possible to have the <span>HH:MM</span> inside the <div> and show it?

Comment: Yes. Only "HH:MM" like normal HTML rendering.